# Cоздание драфта(черновика)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Допустим у меня есть форма отправки письма. Я начинаю что-то печатать. Вдруг мне захотелось перейти на другие вкладки сайта(новости, товары и тд. неважно). Теперь я опять возвращаюсь на форму отправки письма, и я хочу чтобы всё, что я написал уже было (напиши в телеграмме сообщение кому-то, но не отправляйте, и выйдите из диалога, поймёте о чём я). php js sql. Подскажите общий план реализации.

Comment: С каждым нажатием кнопки можете записывать в `$_SESSION['draft']`, или когда пользователь будет переходить на страницу сделать подтверждение. А на странице выводить эту сессию. `<textarea><?= $_SESSION['draft'] ?></textarea>`

Comment: @entithat, с каждым нажатием слишком жирно будет. Смена фокуса, таймер секунд на пять - самое то.

Comment: @Other, возможно. Ещё лучше один раз при выходе из страницы :)

Comment: @entithat, это перебор. Печатаешь кучу символов, разметку делаешь и тут браузер упал/компьютер вырубился/колдунство произошло и всё.

Comment: @Other, нуу.. тогда золотая середина :)